# VS Code with code-server (circa version 4.2.0-4.16.0) always asks for login credential after restart

Tags: linux, authentication, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to add **"password-store":"basic"** in **arv.json** file but i could not find this file by searching **Preerences:Configure Runtime Agruments** command in command palette.

[no arv.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qWLh.png)

[always ask for login on restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhDw5.png).

I'm running VS Code server on chrome with proot-fedora on **termux**. It's annoying for me as VSCode always ask for login credentials when ever i restart it.

In my case gnome-keyring don't work & seahorse is GUI programme which i can not run on a terminal emulator on android device.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a possible case of [[Bug]: GitHub login status gets lost after restarting of code-server daemon #5072](https://github.com/coder/code-server/issues/5072).

A fix for that bug has been purportedly made by PR [Enable secret storage #6450](https://github.com/coder/code-server/pull/6450).

As for before the fix gets released or if it doesn't work, you might find [this comment there](https://github.com/coder/code-server/issues/5072#issuecomment-1703762507) helpful at least as a temporary workaround. Ex. for GitHub login, you can set `github-auth` in the config file, or set the `GITHUB_TOKEN` environment variable when starting `code-server`, or use the `--github-auth` argument when running `code-server`. For GitLab extensions, similar applies: use the `GITLAB_WORKFLOW_INSTANCE_URL` or `GITLAB_WORKFLOW_TOKEN` environment variables for `code-server`.